# Error using nested MAP structure in Java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to put map into another but have an error when this goes longer.

Map1

```
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Map2

```
Map<Map<String,String>, List> outerMap = new HashMap<Map<String,String>, List>();
```

Map3

```
Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap = new   HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List>();
```

I am trying to put map1 into map2 and then map2 into map3 but the declaration statement gives me an error. Can anyone suggest. Thanks.

```
    Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    innerMap.put(key,value); 

    List articleTitleList = new ArrayList(); 
    Map<Map<String,String>, List> outerMap = new HashMap<Map<String,String>, List>();    

    outerMap.put(innerMap,articleTitleList); 
    List articleList = new ArrayList(); 
    Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap = new HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List>(); 
    returnValueMap.put(outerMap,articleList)
```

Comment: Can you share the code, the way you are trying to do that?

Comment: What error? Make `List` Generic.

Comment: there is no error in posted 3 statements, add mroe detail to get answer

Comment: The declaration works for me

Comment: You can also use diamond <> operator to avoid writing twice.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question. That also compiles fine. Still, don't use raw types.

Comment: Thanks all, had issues with the method data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<Map<String,String>, List> outerMap = new HashMap<Map<String,String>, List>();
    Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap = new HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List>();

}
```

This compiles and runs for me, check that you have no typos or issues. I would also highly, highly, highly, not recommend using a map as a key for another map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Guava** or **diamond** operator to avoid typos and writing same twice. For example:

**Map1**

```
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

changes to:

```
Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<>(); // Diamond operator
Map<String, String> innerMap2 = Maps.newHashMap(); // Using Guava
```

Or **Map3**

```
Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap = new   HashMap<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List>();
```

changes to

```
Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap = new HashMap<>(); // Diamond operator
Map<Map<Map<String,String>, List>, List> returnValueMap2 = Maps.newHashMap(); // Using Guava
```